# Drop event not working to divisions which created by for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to create drag and drop event in javascript. I get the data from the database by using a loop and create div according to that data. Then I try to catch `drop()` event when dropped an item. But its not working. But Its works on hard coded div.

```
for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            html += '<div class="column left first" ondrop="drop(event)" >';
            html += '<ul class="sortable-list" id="pakageItemsUl_' + i + '">';
            html += '</ul>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
      html += '</div>';
}
$('#PositonsDiv').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript events should be applied separately; you can't enable them inside document fragments:

```
for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    var $list = $('<ul class="sortable-list"></ul>')
        .prop('id', 'packageItemsUl_' + i);

    $('<div class="column left first"></div>')
        .on('drop', drop)
        .append($list)
        .appendTo('#PositionsDiv');
}
```